# Element of a sigma-algebra versus a subset of sigma-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

What is the difference between a set being an element of a $\sigma$-algebra compared to being a subset of a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: The same difference as a subset of the real numbers, say, vs being a real number. (The fact is that you are considering subsets and elements of a given set, you are not using anything in particular of the sigma field.)

Comment: @user0102 I despise the point system of SE in general, so I prefer give short-answers in the comments. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Omega$ be a nonempty set. We say that a class of subsets of $\Omega$ denoted by $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra iff

1. $\Omega\in\Sigma$,
2. $A^{c}\in\Sigma$ whenever $A\in\Sigma$,
3. $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions, that is to say:
   \begin{align*}
   A_{k}\in\Sigma \Rightarrow \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\in\Sigma
   \end{align*}

So the first is a subset of $\Omega$ and the second is a set of subsets from $\Omega$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you! makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

A subset of a $\sigma$-algebra is a set of sets, but an element of a $\sigma$-algebra is a set of elements of the underlying space.  For example, if we take $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$ and the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F := \{\emptyset, \{1,2,3\}, \{1\},\{2,3\} \}$ then $\{1\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}$ are elements of $\mathcal F$, while $\{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$ or $\{\{1\}, \{2,3\}\}$ are subsets of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Very helpful!